# After recent shared hosting updates to Php, MySQL and Apache my site is not pulling data from MySQL (1064 syntax error)

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, mysql-error-1064

Newbie here. My hosting company recently upgraded their server(s) and that's where my website problems began:

FYI:

- MySQL upgraded from 5.1.70 to version 5.5.32
- Apache upgraded from 2.2.25 to version 2.4.6
- PHP upgraded from 5.3.27 to version 5.4.22
- I have a shared hosting account

For the last 2 days I've been searching Google, online manuals and developer/tech forums for possible answers to my "issues" and I'm having no luck finding good answers that help me fix my code to make my website display properly. Very frustrating. Obviously I need to learn more.

BKGD: I hired a developer to build a CMS for my website a couple of years ago and have since been trying to learn so I have a VERY basic understanding of Php, MySQL and HTML... but obviously not enough to fix these issues. ***Can you/anyone please help me get closer to fixing this nightmare.***

1. I know my original website code worked fine a week ago - prior to the hosting updates.
2. The Index page and other "main Sections" currently display just fine for some reason. But if you click on any of the links to "articles", "news" and other "pages", those pages are not connecting properly >> not pulling table data from the associated MySQL database. Those pages showed a couple of different error messages.... initially displayed ONLY a "1064 syntax error" message OR "no page found" error (no "header", "footer", "page title", or any other info). I've since tweaked the code (I.e., I "hid" some of it with "//") and have it displaying the header and footer but nothing from MySQL database.
3. The original "php.ini" file needed extra code >> "register_globals=on" << to work properly after the second-to-last Php & MySQL update. That is now "deprecated" and "removed".
4. This newbie thinks that the following code is ONE EXAMPLE that isn't working properly (that I believe needs to be edited/updated to allow it to connect to MySQL). I think if I figure this one out I can apply similar tweaks to the other "news" and "article" pages:

⁣

```
//-- START: SAMPLE CODE ----

include "init.php";

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$prefix}pages WHERE pag_name='$page_name'") or report();

if (mysql_num_rows($res)==1)
    cdie("no page found");
else
    $row=fetch($res);

$title = "$row[pag_title]";
$desc = "$row[pag_description]";

//------- END: SAMPLE CODE --
```

I realize I might be way off on this being the issue (E.g., the problem might be in the `functions.php` file) but that's where I'm at right now. Clueless. Ugh.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Need more info (just ask and I'll reply as soon as I get the email).

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated. Use mysqli_ or PDO

Answer (score 1):

If your code relies on `register_globals`, you are going to run into undefined variable problems.

For example, if the `$page_name` variable comes from a query string like `index.php?page_name=test`, you could access it before like `$page_name` but now you must access it like `$_GET['page_name']`.

You need to check all your code to see if your variables are defined (a good IDE can help with that).

As a sidenote, you also need to double-check to see if you don't have any sql injection problems, injecting variables directly in a query is normally not a good sign. You should really switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements but at the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your variables before you use them in your queries.